# How to propagate updated baggage key back to client from remote server? || spring cloud sleuth

Tags: java, logging, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

We are currently using spring cloud sleuth for trace context propagation throughout our microservices and it is working perfectly fine.

I have one requirement where let us say we have three services **A,B and C** and for every request we receive, we create one custom [baggage key](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/project-features.html#features-baggage) at service A and propogate it through B and C.

here is the ask, the flow of any request is like **A->B->C**
.
I want to update the Baggage key in service B and propagate this update to A so that server A will start printing new Baggage key in its trace context once it receives response from B.

As a custom solution, we can receive this updated baggage key in the response header and set it on the trace context but I am looking for more clean approach to handle this through sping cloud sleuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing else there in Sleuth / Micrometer Tracing better than what you're currently doing as a custom solution

Answer (score 0):

All services can use a filter class. If request has a baggage field, filter concats -> and appRoute of current service. If there is no baggage field, filter sets appRoute of current service.

For example;

if A calls B and B calls C :

*A service output:*

Route=A

*B service output:*

Route=A->B

*C service output:*
Route:A->B->C

### application.yaml file for A service:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: A-service
  sleuth:
    baggage:
      remote-fields: app-route
      correlation-enabled: true
      correlation-fields: app-route
system:
  app-route:
   name: A
```

Other services system.app-route.name value could be B and C

### Configuration for injecting BaggageField

```
@Configuration
public class SleuthConfiguration {

     @Bean
     BaggageField appRouteField() {
        return BaggageField.create("app-route");
     }
}
```

### Filter class for all services:

```
public class LogFilter implements Filter {

@Autowired
private BaggageField appRouteBaggageField;

@Value(value = "${system.app-route.name:}")
private String appRouteName;

@Value(value = "${spring.application.name:-}")
private String applicationName;

private String appName;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    appName = (appRouteName == null || appRouteName.isEmpty()) ? applicationName : appRouteName;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) {
    updateAppRouteBaggageField();
    logger.info("Route={}",appRouteBaggageField.getValue());
}

private void updateAppRouteBaggageField() {
    String appRouteBaggageFieldValue = appRouteBaggageField.getValue();
    appRouteBaggageField.updateValue((appRouteBaggageFieldValue == null || appRouteBaggageFieldValue.isEmpty())
            ? appName : (appRouteBaggageFieldValue + "->" + appName));
}
}
```

### build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
```